# Multiple check for "None" - what would be the proper way in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup for parsing html, I often find my self with the following code:

```
result.find("some_tag").attrs['some_attribute']
```

What would be the proper way to verify if find method didn't return None and also to check if there is a such key in attributes without nested "if" statement ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One line answer**:

```
 attr_val = result.find('some_tag').attrs.get('some_attr', None) if result.find('some_tag') else None
```

I have used `get` method for `attrs` dict to get a value if it exists in it, else None.

Answer (score 0):

I would split it to 2 checks - if `result.find()` returned `None`, and if there is `some_attribute`.

```
find_result = result.find("some_tag")
if find_result:
    try:
        find_result.attrs["some_attribute"]
    except KeyError as e:
        print("some_attribute not found!")
```